# Как настроить twig чтобы задавать неполный адрес изображения в шаблоне?

Tags: url, kohana, twig, img

Прислали шаблон сайта с использованием twig. Адреса изображений заданы не полностью, например img src="images/img1.png". При использовании mvc kohana  возникают проблемы при отображении изображений. Можно ли настроить twig так, чтобы подобные адреса изображений он по итогу на сайте выводил полностью? Имею ввиду так: http://site.ru/site/images/img1.png.

Answer (score 0):

Нет нельзя. Можно взять пример из symfony и обернуть все эти адреса в функцию img_url(‘/images/image.jpg’), которая будет строить пути как вам захочется. Название функции может быть любое